# Random retornando sempre o mesmo número

Tags: c#, random

Tenho um método que sua função é retornar 25 números aleatórios em uma lista:

```
static List<int> criarList()
{
    List<int> lista = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        lista.Add(new Random().Next(0, 100));
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Mas por algum motivo, ele só retorna os mesmos números, ou seja, todos iguais:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que isso está ocorrendo? Como concertar?

Comment: A classe `Random` parece gerar uma sequência de números que atendem a certos requisitos estatísticos de aleatoriedade. A sequência é gerada a partir de uma semente padrão, baseada no tempo. Não seria o problema de todas as instâncias da classe estarem utilizando a mesma semente e, assim, gerando a mesma sequência? Por quê não chama o método `Next` da mesma instância as 25 vezes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A classe [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) usa um algoritmo para gerar a sequência de números (pseudo)aleatórios.
Essa sequência é iniciada com base num valor denominado *seed*. Diferentes valores geram diferentes sequências.

O construtor [Random()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) usa o relógio do sistema para obter o *seed*.

Como você está a [construir várias instâncias num curto espaço de tempo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx#Multiple) o *seed* é sempre o mesmo, originado sempre a mesma sequência.

Use apenas uma instância:

```
static List<int> criarList()
{
    List<int> lista = new List<int>();
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        lista.Add(random.Next(0, 100));
    }
    return lista;
}
```