# O HttpClient deve, ou não deve, ser utilizado dentro de um bloco using?

Tags: c#, .net, using, dispose

Ao ler esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/422626/2541), a uma pergunta relacionada com a utilização do `using`, fiquei curioso em relação à afirmação seguinte:

> Na verdade todo mundo usa `HttpClient` errado, eu mesmo já usei e não sabia de tudo, porque eu confiei que a documentação tinha tudo o que eu precisava, mas aprendi a lição.

A forma como eu tenho visto `HttpClient` ser usado é dentro de um bloco *using*.

```
using (var http = new HttpClient())
{
    //
}
```

Não sabendo ao certo se era a isto que o AR se referia, perguntei-lhe e, através de um [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422625/como-funciona-a-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-using-e-do-garbage-collector-do-net#comment821003_422626), ele confirmou que sim.

Não tendo sido o comentário suficientemente esclarecedor, fica então a pergunta:

O `HttpClient` deve, ou não deve, ser utilizado dentro de um bloco `using`?

Comment: Em uma época que [não tinha isso na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193681(v=vs.118)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), eu não sei nem se no começo o objeto tinha comportamento diferente. Tem umas coisas que ensinam errado lá ainda. A Microsoft me convidou pra melhorar algumas coisas, mas é difícil cuidar de tanta coisa. E não sei até que ponto posso mexer mesmo. A resposta aqui diz basicamente o que precisa e é mais importante, se eu achar que precisa mais eu dou uma resposta.

Comment: Dá uma lida nisto: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ e isto é útil também: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients E recomendo ler isto pra entendimento mais profundo https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/370742/389 E ainda pode ser útil: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/

Comment: @Maniero Obrigado, fiquei esclarecido.

Comment: Uma dúvida, é muito comum hoje em dia utilizar injeção de dependência. Neste caso, injetar um HttpClient pode ser um problema? Poderia explicar melhor como funciona o 'using' e 'dispose' nas injeções de dependencias?

Comment: @BrunoWarmling sim, DI é muito mal usado, neste caso é bem errado mesmo :)

Comment: @BrunoWarmling qual a razão para querer injectar um HttpClient?

Comment: @ramaral teste?

Comment: Por exemplo, tenho utilizado o pattern CQRS. Em um dos meus comandos, tenho o HttpClient como dependência, para consumir uma API. Esse HttpClient por sua vez é criado por um HttpClientFactory afim de incluir decorators e lidar com a parte da autenticação dessa API. Dai agora lendo isso tudo... surgiu a dúvida se não estou fazendo isso tudo errado...

Comment: @Maniero não vejo necessidade. Posso estar a ver mal mas a classe que usa o HttpClient deve ser sujeita a testes de integração e não a testes unitários.

Comment: @ramaral pode ser mas não não vê uma cenário que precise mockar essa classe pra ela te entregar os dados sem fazer uso do HTTP de verdade?

Comment: @Maniero O que você mocka é a classe que usa o HttpClient, então não precisa dele. Se a razão da DI é testes então o objecto injectado tem de ser mockável, como você faria um mock de um HttpClient?

Comment: @ramaral até concordo embora eu acho que em casos assim muitas vezes não precisa de DI (dá longa discussão), mas pode ter alguma caso que precisa o nível mais próximo. O mock seria uma classe com a mesma API mas que responde com dados controlados em vez de fazer conexão.

Comment: @Maniero Isso é a definição de mock. A minha pergunta é como fazê-lo. HttpClient só implementa IDisposable, não expõe a "API". Então como o injecta? Qualquer que seja o método de injecção usado, é esperado um tipo HttpClient.

Comment: @ramaral isso é verdade, ele nem foi feito pensado nisto. É que eu acho isso tudo tão errado que até tentei achar um jeito de usar pra não parecer radical e... não deu :D

Comment: @Maniero Não dá directamente. Mas, se tiver o empenho necessário, defina uma interface com os métodos que quer usar do HttpClient . Depois, faça um wrapper sobre ele, que implemente essa interface, e use-o em vez dele. No entanto o melhor é manter-se radical. :)

Comment: @Maniero Parece que a questão "de como usar" foi solucionada com [HttpClientFactory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O grande problema é justamente que ele é enganoso. Por ter implementado a interface `IDisposble` todo mundo acha que deveria usar o `using`. E não sei se na primeira implementação desta classe não precisava, o que eu sei é que [a documentação inicialmente não falava nada disto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193681(v=vs.118)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), ou porque ensinava errado mesmo ou porque antes era assim (não pode confiar 100% em documentação, algo próximo disto pode, mas ela nunca dá todos detalhes).

Faz algum sentido ter essa interface nessa classe porque de fato pode ter motivos para em algum momento o recurso vinculado a este objeto seja descartado. Porém o mais comum no uso correto é que ele dure a aplicação toda.

Pensa bem no objeto, começando pelo nome. As pessoas pensam nele como se fosse uma conexão mas ele é um cliente. Quantos clientes HTTP você precisa na sua aplicação? Um, não é? Pra que outros? Ele é um mecanismo, é como uma *file system*, não tem porque ter mais que um. O fato de você ter um só não quer dizer que só pode fazer uma requisição, ele estando lá pode requisitar sempre que quiser, desde que tenha acesso ao objeto.

Por alguma razão não há algo estático nele como a *file system*, provavelmente porque o cliente é pouco pesado e criar sempre será algo caro para maioria das aplicações, ao mesmo tempo que criar toda vez que precisa é custoso demais (que é o erro que "todo mundo" faz).

Na forma correta é muito comum que este objeto seja colocado em um campo estático, assim cria uma vez, possivelmente na primeira utilização efetiva, e não precisa mais, aí é só usar.

O exemplo da outra resposta não é muito bom porque foi escrito de qualquer jeito. Eu imagino que a intenção ali era que o campo fosse estático. A não ser em um exemplo muito simples não parece adequado criar na classe principal, deveria ter uma classe com responsabilidade de cuidar disto, mas aí não é um erro de uso do `HttpClient` e sim de organização do código.

## Eu aprendi que se a classe tiver `IDisposable` sempre deve usar `using`

Não é bem assim, deve em métodos, ou seja, quando o objeto deve ser criado localmente. E esse deve é relativo, também tem casos para não usar, ainda que provavelmente tem jeito melhor de fazer.

Existem casos que você pode criar o objeto ali, retorná-lo e aí o objeto deve reter o recurso vinculado a ele, então não é ali que o usará o `using`, mas provavelmente usará em outro lugar para que a liberação seja feita. Por sorte você não vê isso por aí, mas é algo que pode existir e até ser útil em algum cenário. Algo assim:

```
void Metodo() {
    ...
    using (var arquivo = CriaRecurso()) { ... }
    ...
}

FileStream CriaRecurso() {
    ...
    var file = new FileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Create)
    ...
    return file;
}
```

Além disto pode ser que o objeto com o recurso pode ser guardado dentro de uma classe através de um campo e não uma variável local. Neste caso não tem como usar o `using` o que você terá que fazer é em algum momento chamar o `Dispose()` desse objeto. Isto pode ser através de um método destrutor/finalizador que todo objeto tem ou através de um `Dispose()` criada nesta classe, portanto se você usar um um objeto que seja `IDisposable` em um campo praticamente obriga essa classe implementar a `IDisposable`, é viral. Aí um objeto dessa sua classe provavelmente será colocado em um `using`.

É mais raro fazer isto, mas já vi vários cenários que precisa. Se as pessoas fizessem assim muito código seria otimizado quando há ganhos.

Em alguns casos deve ser até mesmo em um campo estático o que pode dispensar essa classe passar por alguma destruição.

O [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) necessário para o objeto determinará onde e se terá o `using`.

## Não pode usar nunca o `using` nessa classe?

Pode, se você sabe que sua aplicação só usará o cliente HTTP ali uma única vez ou uma quantidade muito limitada, então melhor não fazer. E não estou dizendo que dá na mesma. É pior fazer isto se for mais de uma vez, só faz sentido se for uma vez mesmo, em todo tempo de execução. De fato em um cenário assim é melhor com o `using`, mas é raro ter um cenário assim.

## O que acontece de errado se fizer assim?

Ele vai criando *sockets* no sistema operacional. Não está claro porque mas ele parece não liberar imediatamente e por isso uma hora pode ficar sem *sockets* livres. Ou mesmo que isto não ocorra cada *socket* novo gasta recursos na máquina.

Há uma [página que mostra isso com propriedade](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/):

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Net.Http;

public class Program {
    public static async Task Main() {
        WriteLine("Starting connections");
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
                var result = await client.GetAsync("http://aspnetmonsters.com");
                WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        WriteLine("Connections done");
    }
}
```

Isto funciona e produz isto:

> ```
> C:\code\socket> dotnet run
> Project socket (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because inputs were modified
> Compiling socket for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
>
> Compilation succeeded.
>     0 Warning(s)
>     0 Error(s)
>
> Time elapsed 00:00:01.2501667
>
>
> Starting connections
> OK
> OK
> OK
> OK
> OK
> OK
> OK
> OK
> OK
> OK
> Connections done
> ```

Porém investigando no sistema operacional veja o que aconteceu:

> ```
> C:\code\socket>NETSTAT.EXE
> ...
>   Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12050      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12051      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12053      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12054      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12055      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12056      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12057      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12058      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12059      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12060      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12061      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    10.211.55.6:12062      waws-prod-bay-017:http  TIME_WAIT
>   TCP    127.0.0.1:1695         SIMONTIMMS742B:1696    ESTABLISHED
> ...
> ```

Ruim, né? Imagina isso acontecendo milhares de vezes.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Net.Http;

public class Program {
    private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    public static async Task Main() {
        WriteLine("Starting connections");
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            var result = await client.GetAsync("http://aspnetmonsters.com");
            WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
        }
        WriteLine("Connections done");
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/HttpClient.cs).

O resultado é o mesmo mas agora o sistema operacional reporta só um *socket*.

Note que isto está ok porque é um exemplo só para testes, o objeto e recurso será descartado no fim da aplicação que é quando desejamos, mas há casos que precise de um controle mais sofisticado. Não ache que sempre essa forma é a mais adequada para seu caso, pro isso é necessário aprender fazer as coisas de forma ampla e não apenas decorar receitas de bolo.

## Conclusão.

Precisamos entender tudo sobre o que vamos usar. Muitas vezes não basta ler a documentação oficial, tem que procurar outros documentos, questionar. Programar é difícil, mesmo tentando fazer tudo certo ainda pode dar algo errado.

O problema é que no passado a documentação não falava que o tempo de vida provavelmente deveria ser o mesmo da aplicação toda.

Algumas leituras recomendadas:

- [Anti Pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Usando `HttpClientFactory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (em muitos casos é mais recomendado fazer isto)
- [Mais informações sobre a fábrica](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#typed-clients)
- [Artigo na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Documentação atual mostra o correto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#Remarks)
- [Discussão sobre o assunto](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/330364/389)

Comment: *"Eu aprendi que se a classe tiver IDisposable sempre deve usar using*" - Ter um professor que nos ensine é bom, mas há algumas vantagens em não ter. Não ter professor proporcionou que eu recolhesse o conhecimento de várias fontes. Dessa recolha "eu aprendi que se a classe tiver IDisposable deve chamar Dispose()". Seja caso de ter ou não professor, o importante, quando aprendemos, é termos sempre uma atitude critica e "desconfiada", no bom sentido, em relação ao que lemos e nos dizem. (...)

Comment: (...) Apesar disso, foi apanhado pelo fenómeno do "o que é repetido vezes e vezes sem conta é verdadeiro/correcto", eu era um dos que usava mal o HttpClient.

Comment: É como o `Random` só que este não implementa `IDisposable` e engana menos :)

Comment: Jugo que se está a referir a [Random retornando sempre o mesmo número](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250515/2541)

Comment: Isso mesmo.....

Comment: *"o objeto e recurso será descartado no fim*" O objecto sim, o recurso não. Certo?

Comment: Ambos, quando a aplicação encerra tudo é descartado. Pode ser que não pelo .NET (aí não sei como está) mas de uma forma ou de outra será descartado porque nada que a aplicação iniciou pode sobreviver depois do seu fim.

Comment: Não ficará a conexão aberta(ESTABLISHED)? Veja o último paragrafo do ponto [2. The (mis?)conception of using IDisposable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/370742).

Comment: @ramaral não vou afirmar que mata na hora que a aplicação encerrar, eu até acho que tem uma espécie de evento que o fim da aplicação manda encerrar isso (coisa interna do sistema operacional), e se não faz deveria fazer, mas mesmo neste caso ainda teria um encerramento por *timeout* ou algo assim, não tem como ficar pendurado sem um dono. Se ficasse seria *bug* e não *by design*.

Answer (score 6):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main()
    {
      try   
      {
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
      }  
      catch(HttpRequestException e)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");  
         Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
      }
    }
```

A instância da classe HttpClient atua como uma sessão para enviar solicitações HTTP. Uma instância de HttpClient é uma coleção de configurações aplicadas a todas as solicitações executadas por essa instância. Além disso, cada instância de HttpClient usa seu próprio pool de conexões, isolando suas solicitações de solicitações executadas por outras instâncias de HttpClient.

De acordo com a documentação encontrada na Microsoft, quando existe uma única instância do HttpClient pra toda a aplicação o ideal é não usar o "Using{}", caso contrário é importante fazer uso do "Using{}" quando existir mais de uma instância do HttpClient.

Comment: Achei curioso as resposta ter poucos votos, ach oque só meu e do AP, mas o final talvez seja culpado disto. Dá um pouco a impressão que você pode usar vários vários objetos e aí ir dispensando com `using`, e até tecnicamente pode mesmo, mas é errado. Essa é a única ressalva que faço.

Comment: @Maniero estava preste a comentar algo do género. O segundo voto não é meu e a razão é essa mesmo. Acho que a resposta não responde completamente à pergunta. É necessário explicar o porquê de usar apenas uma instância ou as consequências de repetidamente usar o HttpClient dentro de um bloco *using*,

Comment: @ramaral no fim achei que realmente deixa a desejar, mas não posso tirar o voto :(